# printing from nested dict: ignore if the key is "None"

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
myDict = {
    "sample-adaptors": {
        "banana-mock": {
            "insts": [
                "i-34d425g5"
            ]
        }
    },
    "cucumber-test": {
        "None": {
            "insts": [
                "i-65j3hue6"
            ]
        }
    },
    "SampleMonitoring": {
        "sample-mon-comp": {
            "insts": [
                "i-754mbde"
            ]
        },
        "None": {
            "insts": [
                "i-981a5134",
                "i-76a25ge1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

from which, I need to formulate the string(s) like this:

```
EC2.sample-adaptors.banana-mock
EC2.cucumber-test
EC2.SampleMonitoring.sample-mon-comp
```

i.e. if the each second key is not `None` it'll be added to the string with the `.`(dot) otherwise not. This is what I've come with, so far....

```
>>> nStr = lambda s: str({'None':''}.get(s,s))
>>> zLen = lambda n: (1 if len(n)>=1 else 0)
>>>
>>> for proj in myDict:
...   for comp in myDict[proj]:
...     print "EC2.{0}{1}".format(proj, ('.'+nStr(comp))*zLen(nStr(comp)))
```

which is working but wondering if it's the way of doing it. Can these two nested for-loop be shorten? The actual dict is very large, so the code should be efficient enough to process the data as quickly as possible. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the depth of the dictionary always 2?

Comment: Wait, are you counting on ordering within a dictionary?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: yes, the depth should be always 2.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need for lambda expressions when you can use a simple if statement:

```
for proj, contents in myDict.items():
    for comp in contents:
        if comp == "None":
            print "EC2.{0}".format(proj)
        else:
            print "EC2.{0}.{1}".format(proj, comp)
```

Remember that there's no guarantee of order in a dictionary. If you want these statements ordered, you'll want to use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes comprehensions are slower (sometimes faster) than explicit loops. Just measure the different approaches.

```
['EC2.{}'.format(k) if k2 == 'None' else 'EC2.{}.{}'.format(k, k2) for k, v in myDict.items() for k2 in v]
```